# Pinning 2015 polygons on a grid

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given 2 square grids with areas of 2015 units sq, each.

Each of the grids is divided into 2015 polygons with an area of 1 unit sq.

The grids are not necessarily identical in their division.

We place the grids on top of each other; prove you can pin all 4030 polygons with 2015 pins.

My attempt:

Suppose that for each polygon there is no overlapping polygon when the grids are placed on top of each other. Then there is an area of 1 unit sq. that is empty.
So we must have at least 1 polygon that overlaps each polygon on the other grid.

We pin in those spots where we have an overlap.

Sufficient?

Thx a lot

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I got it from a review session for a test in a Discrete Math course..